# Google Maps change marker graphic on mouseover

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Can someone help me figure out why my code below does not work to change the marker graphic on mouseover?  I have the marker.setIcon in each mouseover / mouseout function, but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    
        var marker, i;
     var id = 'sites';
     
     for (i = 0; i < locations_beer.length; i++) {  
       
       var id = 'sites' + i;
       
       var contentString = '<div class="beer-map-popup">'+ locations_beer[i][0] +'<br /><img src="_img/beer-map-popup-wheat.png" border="0" /></div>';
           
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content: contentString
         });
   
     
      
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_beer[i][1], locations_beer[i][2]),
            map: map
      ,id: id
      ,icon: 'http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin.png'
      ,url: locations_beer[i][4]
      ,zIndex:100
       });
       
       var icon1 = "http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin-active.png";
       var icon2 = "http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin.png";

            
       (function(infowindow) {
   
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                 infowindow.open(map, this);
        marker.setIcon("http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin-active.png");
             });
     
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                 infowindow.close();
        marker.setIcon("http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin.png");
             });
        })(infowindow);
        
     
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have function closure on `marker` in your mouseover/mouseout listener.
The `this` inside the mouseover/mouseout listener function is the marker.  One option would be to change your code to use `this.setIcon(...)` rather than `marker.setIcon(...)`.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03nb673k/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  var marker, i;
  var id = 'sites';
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations_beer.length; i++) {

    var id = 'sites' + i;

    var contentString = '<div class="beer-map-popup">' + locations_beer[i][0] + '<br /><img src="_img/beer-map-popup-wheat.png" border="0" /></div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_beer[i][1], locations_beer[i][2]),
      map: map,
      id: id,
      icon: 'http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin.png',
      url: locations_beer[i][4],
      zIndex: 100
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    var icon1 = "http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin-active.png";
    var icon2 = "http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin.png";


    (function(infowindow) {

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        this.setIcon("http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin-active.png");
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        this.setIcon("http://www.ashtonbrewingcompany.com/_img/beermap-pin.png");
      });
    })(infowindow);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var mapOptions = {};
var locations_beer = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```